# Android. Thread и Activity. Memory Leak

Tags: java, android

В ходе углубленного изучения многопоточности в Android встал вопрос.

Хранит ли Thread (Или любые другие Java объекты) ссылку на объект Activity, в котором он (Thread) был создан? Если так, то почему не возникает Memory Leak величиной в то самое Activity при повороте экрана к примеру.

Comment: могу только наблюдением поделиться: когда вы запускаете thread и поворачиваете экран, то ничего не происходит - система ждет завершения thread

Comment: если ссылку на активити в тред не передавать, то нет

Answer (score 2):

Объект хранит ссылку на сущность, в которой он создан если:

1. реализован как внутренний (в том числе анонимный) класс в классе этой сущности
2. ссылка на сущность передана туда явно и записана в поле объекта

Но поток сам по себе может быть источником утечки памяти.
Поскольку не уничтожается сборщиком мусора, пока он выполняется (запущен, но не завершён), даже если у нас нет на него ни одной ссылки.
Соответственно удерживается в памяти и всё, на что объект потока ссылается.
Утечь поток может очень просто:

```
// создали объект потока
new Thread(){
    public boolean runnung = true;
    public void run(){
        // какой-то повторяющийся, ожидающий или длительно выполняющийся код
        while(runnung){
            // ...
        }
    }
}.start(); // запустили поток
// а ссылку-то на объект потока не сохранили
// дальше мы не можем его завершить, так не имеем к нему доступа
```

При повороте экрана мы тоже можем потерять поток, так как ссылка на него осталась в экземпляре активности, которая больше не доступна.
Поэтому нужно связывать работу потока с жизненным циклом активности (служб и ресиверов это тоже касается между прочим) - завершать потоки при её завершении.
Для загрузки данных, необходимых для показа в активности лучше использовать специальные решения, типа https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel , которые учитывают жизненный цикл и пересоздание активностей.
Если требуется выполнять задачу независимо от жизненного цикла активности, то стоит подумать об её реализации в службе.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не будете сохранять в вашем `Thread` ссылки на `Context` или любые другие объекты которые хранят в себе ссылки на `Context` (таких как `View`), то не будет утечек.

Сам по себе `Thread` не может вообще хранить в себе ссылок на `Context`, так как он вообще не знает о существовании. `Thread` это сугубо `Java` класс, `Android Framework` для него неизвестная сущность. Утечки зачастую происходят из-за того, что те кто используют `Thread` передают какие-то данные обратно в `Activity`, а вот для этого как раз и необходимо хранить в себе `Context`. Именно поэтому и нужно заботиться о об остановки `Thread-а` при уничтожении `Activity`.